# how can you sort json list with jq

Tags: arrays, json, sorting, jq

I have the following list:

```
{
    "list": [
        {
            "ipv4": [
                "192.168.64.193"
            ],
            "name": "node2",
            "release": "20.04 LTS",
            "state": "Running"
        },
        {
            "ipv4": [
                "192.168.64.192"
            ],
            "name": "node1",
            "release": "20.04 LTS",
            "state": "Running"
        }
    ]
}

jq -r '.list[] | [ .name, .ipv4[0] ] | @tsv' file.json

node2   192.168.64.193
node1   192.168.64.192
```

How can I sort the list?

I am trying to sort by .name:

```
jq -r 'sort_by(.name) | .list[] | [ .name, .ipv4[0] ] | @tsv' file.json
Cannot index array with string "name"

jq -r 'sort_by(.list[].name) | .list[] | [ .name, .ipv4[0] ] | @tsv' file.json
Cannot index array with string "name"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert `sort_by(.name)` after traversing to `.list` but before iterating over its items with `[]`:

```bash
jq -r '.list | sort_by(.name)[] | [.name, .ipv4[0]] | @tsv' file.json
```

```json
node1   192.168.64.192
node2   192.168.64.193
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/E6KWtZMF6c4)